# Not able to play custom sound on react-native-push-notification in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

const RemotePushController = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Create a custom notification channel for Android (Optional, but recommended)
    PushNotification.createChannel(
      {
        channelId: '6', // Replace with a unique channel ID
        channelName: 'newOrder 6', // Replace with the desired channel name
        soundName: 'buzzer.mp3', // Replace with the filename of your custom sound
        importance: 4, // Importance level (Android 8.0+). Set to 4 (IMPORTANCE_HIGH) for high-priority notifications.
      },
      created => console.log('Custom channel created:', created)
    );

    PushNotification.configure({
      // Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: function (token) {
        console.log('TOKEN:', token);
        global.token = token['token'];
      },

      // Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        console.log('REMOTE NOTIFICATION ==>', notification);
        const localNotification = {
          channelId: '6', // Use the same channel ID used in createChannel
          title: notification.title || '',
          message: notification.message || '',
          soundName: 'res://raw/buzzer.mp3', // Play the custom sound if provided, otherwise, the default sound will be used
          vibrate: true,
          vibration: 300,
          playSound: true,
        };

        // Display the custom notification
        PushNotification.localNotification(localNotification);
        // Process the notification here
      },

      // Android only: GCM or FCM Sender ID
      senderID: '',

      // Custom channel ID for Android (Optional, but recommended)
      channelId: '6', // Replace with the same channel ID used in createChannel

      // Enable pop-up notifications when the app is in the foreground (Optional)
      popInitialNotification: true,

      // Request permissions to show notifications (Optional, required for iOS)
      requestPermissions: true,
      permissions: {
        sound: true,
      },
    });
  }, []);

  return null;
};

export default RemotePushController;
```

There are two sounds getting set as default for a channel so because of that the default notification sound is not getting played.So we have the sound path in res://raw/ file inside our android/src/main folder but still we are facing this issue . We tried changing the Sound path to buzzer and as well buzzer.mp3 but the problem is these sounds are been set as default in our device and Since there are two default sounds which are already present the android is choosing the Default sound which already exists .